# Add certain text to the end of any validation error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add 'Notice that you have to select all the images and related vehicles again.' to the end of any validation error, regardless of how many errors there are, so for example adding this text to the end of every error message isn't an option, because it will be shown many times if there is more than one error.

Is there any way to add particular text to the end of validation error message?

Tried to google but didn't found anything.

Comment: You can add it to where you are displaying the errors in your view.  That said I think the proper solution is to not require the user to reselect the images and related vehicles again but that is strictly an assumption.

Comment: Of course, but for now have to leave it like this as there is more important things to deal with. Will try your solution tomorrow, but feels like there should be better way than putting it in to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily accomplished however it may be tedious depending on how many validations you have listed.  I will give some examples so you can decide on what best suites your needs:

If using Rails' built-in validations (such as prescence, uniqueness, etc.) you can add your own message inside the validation along with the standard output or replace it completely with your own:

```
  validates :username, :email, :title, :another_attribute,:omg_another_attribute, :password, presence: { :message => "cant be blank.  Notice that you have to select all the images and related vehicles again for not filling out the form ya dumbo!"}
```

This will list the error message for every field they left blank.  If you want to add an error just once at the end of all the error messages to remind them of this problem you can make a custom validation that checks for other errors and then appends its own, one time, at the end like:

```
#Make sure to put this custom validate method after all the other validators since they are run in order from top to bottom and you want to see if the others have failed 
validate :add_blanket_error_when_one_or_more_errors_happen

def add_blanket_error_when_one_or_more_errors_happen
  if self.errors.count > 0 then self.errors.add(:base, "Notice you were being dumb again and now have to fill more stuff out.") end
end
```

I normally add generic errors like this to the 'base' field but you can attach it to any field in your form if you dont want to add extra styling/markup.  In your view if you chose to add it to the 'base' field you can put this message right at the top of the form if it exists by doing:

```
      <% unless @the_form_object_youre_using_here.errors[:base].blank? %>
        <div>
          <span class="error-explanation"><%= @again_the_form_object_here.errors[:base].first %></span>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

This will also let you style the span etc.

Unfortunately there is no simple one-liner you can add to your model to append a blanket message to all failed validations.  Even trying something seemingly harmless like a custom validation to accomplish it(**DONT TRY THIS UNLESS YOU HAVE your task-manager ready** because it will cause a memory leak and even make your computer crash if you dont kill the process quickly)

```
**DONT DO IT IF YOU ENJOY COORS LIGHT OR PREFER LONG WALKS ON THE BEACH**

  validate :append_messages_to_all_failed_validations

  def append_messages_to_all_failed_validations
    self.errors.each do |attribute, error|
       #**YOU SHOULDNT BE DOING THIS LOL**
       self.errors[attribute.to_sym] = "#{error} plus some"
    end
  end
```